# How to Save / Load game-time? (Unity Engine)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, time

I have two scenes in my game - Main Menu and Game. I already made player's position and rotation persist between 2 scenes using binary formatter and serialization. But, I struggle to make time in the Game scene persist between 2 scenes (and game sessions). To put it simply:

1. Game starts - the time is 'x'.
2. I save the Game after some time and leave / go to Menu - the time is 'x + time passed'.
3. I load the Game - the time is 'x + time passed' instead of 'x'.

I paste some code (saving and loading pos & rot) so you have an idea of what's going on.

```
public static class DataSerializer
{
    public static void SerializeData(Player player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        string dataPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.txt";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Create);
        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        bf.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static float[] DeserializeData()
    {
        string dataPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/data.txt";
        if (File.Exists(dataPath))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = bf.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;

            stream.Close();
            return data.stats;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("File does not exist.");
            return new float[6];
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public float[] stats;

    public PlayerData(Player player)
    {
        stats = new float[6];

        stats[0] = player.transform.position.x;
        stats[1] = player.transform.position.y;
        stats[2] = player.transform.position.z;

        stats[3] = player.transform.eulerAngles.x;
        stats[4] = player.transform.eulerAngles.y;
        stats[5] = player.transform.eulerAngles.z;
    }
}
```

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {
        float[] loadedStats = DataSerializer.DeserializeData();

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(loadedStats[0], loadedStats[1], loadedStats[2]);
        Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(loadedStats[3], loadedStats[4], loadedStats[5]);

        player.transform.position = position;
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        DataSerializer.SerializeData(this);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if you would help me with saving & loading game-time in the same way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why so complicated with that `float[]`. In my eyes it just makes it hard to read/understand and is error prone.

I would simply use a structure like the following (if you don't like it - sure stick to `float[7]` why not ^^)

**Update**

**NOTE: [Do not use `BinaryFormatter` anymore!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)** → using `JsonUtility` instead

```
public static class DataSerializer
{
    private static readonly dataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data.txt");

    public static void SerializeData(Player player)
    {
        var data = new PlayerData(player);
        var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);

        File.WriteAllText(dataPath, json);
    }

    public static bool DeserializeData(out PlayerData data)
    {
        data = null;

        if (!File.Exists(dataPath)) 
        {
            Debug.LogError("File does not exist.");
            return false;
            // alternatively create some default data instead
        }
        
        var json = File.ReadAllText(dataPath);
        var data = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerData>(json);

        return true;
    }            
}

[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public SerializableVector3 Position;
    public SerializableVector3 EulerAngles;
    public float TotalTimePlayed;

    public PlayerData(Player player)
    {
        Position = player.transform.position;

        EulerAngles = player.transform.eulerAngles;

        TotalPlayTime = player.TotalTimePlayed;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializableVector3
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;

    public SerializableVector3(Vector3 vec)
    {
        x = vec.x;
        y = vec.y;
        z = vec.z;
    }

    public Vector3 ToVector3()
    {
        return new Vector3(x,y,z);
    }

    public static implicit operator Vector3(SerializableVector3 vec)
    {
        return vec.ToVector3();
    }

    public static implicit operator SerializableVector3(Vector3 vec)
    {
        return new SerializableVector3(vec);
    }
}
```

Then for tracking the total played time there are multiple ways.

- Either store the last save [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) so you can simply add the time currently played when saving:

  ```
   float timePlayedThisSession = (DateTime.Now - dateTimeLastSaved).TotalSeconds;
  ```

  Pro: The system handles it and it's a one time calculation

  Con: The user can simply change the system time -> possibly "hack" your app stats
- Or you can simply use [`Time.unscaledTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledTime.html) which anyway is the time since the last app start.

  Pro: User can not simply alter this value

  Con: Depending on your use case you might not be able to use the `Time.unscaledTime` if e.g. you allow to reset to the last save within your app (because in this case the `Time.time` simply continues counting up **since app start**)
- Or you can go fully "manual" and track the played time fully on your own using [`Time.unscaledDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html) like e.g.

  ```
   private float timePlayedThisSession;

   private void Update()
   {
       timePlayedThisSession += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
   }
  ```

  Pro: Full control + can easily reset or load a value into that field.

  Con: Overhead for the `Update` method being called every frame ... but this is so small that it won't matter at all! ;)

Fazit I would go with the last option and do e.g.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    private float totalTimePlayed;

    // Read-only access
    public float TotalTimePlayed => totalTimePlayed;

    void Start()
    {
        ResetToLastSave ();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        totalTimePlayed += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
    }

    // Just adding this to show you could even simply add a method to allow your user revert to the last save
    public void ResetToLastSave()
    {
        if(!DataSerializer.DeserializeData(out var loadedStats))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Could not load!", this);
            return;
        }

        player.transform.position = loadedStats.Position;
        player.transform.eulerAngles = loadedStats.Rotation;
        totalTimePlayed = loadedStats.TotalTimePlayed;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        DataSerializer.SerializeData(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Big thanks! I’m still a newbie to C# and serialization, and your detailed answer gave me a lot of clues about how everything works.